# onListItemClick() Start/Stop Song

Tags: android

Well, I have a ListView with sounds. When I clicked on one of them, it start playing that song, but when I clicked other one/ones, it's still playing. What I want to do is to stop that sound when I press on the other one. I google it, found exactly same question over here with solution, but it won't work for me. I get error, which says : "The method setDataSource(String) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (int)". I just don't know how to get what specific position, which Item Row was clicked. This is what I have for now in my onListItemClick() method:

```
@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Minions s = (Minions) mSounds.get(position);
        MediaPlayer mPlayer;

        final boolean isPlaying = false;

        if(!isPlaying){
            mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mPlayer.setDataSource(s.getSoundResourceId());
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.start();
            isPlaying = true; 

        }else{

            isPlaying = false;
            mPlayer.stop();
            mPlayer.reset();
            mPlayer.setDataSource(s.getSoundResourceId());
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.start();
            isPlaying = true;

        }

        mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mPlayer) {
                mPlayer.release();
                isPlaying = false;
            }

        });

    }
```

Comment: to get the position use "position"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it,  in your case:

instead:

```
        mediaPlayer= new MediaPlayer();
         mediaPlayer.setDataSource(s.getSoundResourceId());
```

use:

```
 mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.blabla);
```

here you don't need `prepare`

```
private  MediaPlayer mPlayer;

....

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {


    final boolean isPlaying = false;

    if(!isPlaying){
        mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.blabla);

        mPlayer.start();
        isPlaying = true; 

    }else{

        isPlaying = false;
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.blabla);           
        mPlayer.start();
        isPlaying = true;            

    }

    mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mPlayer) {
            mPlayer.release();
            isPlaying = false;
        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try `setDataSource(""+s.getSoundResourceId());`

instead of `setDataSource(s.getSoundResourceId());`

**PS.** also initialize `mPlayer`

like  `MediaPlayer mPlayer=new MediaPlayer();` instead of `MediaPlayer mPlayer;`

and remove this `mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();` from your if condition !

Comment: When I do this, it says "Unhandled exception type IOException" and offers to surround with try/catch. When I surrounding it (a couple of times) I getting another error : "The local variable mPlayer may not have been initialized" so it initializes to null and app crashes.

Comment: @Danger so u must initialize mPlayer !